# Javascript, Regex, Reverse match

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to get the following using js regex:

```
string</span>string</span>string</span>theStrngIWant
```

In one sentence i try to get any characters including new lines after the last `</span>`

I try this pattern `/<\/span>((.|\n)*)/i`, I know the pattern won't work i just wanted to show what i want to capture:

So after the last `</span>` i want to capture anything included in the `.` token and because its not include new lines i added `\n`, I think its ok to use greedy without `?` because its the end of the string anyway, **Also just to note i did try negative lookahead.**

If any one know any regex for this case i will be very thankful.

Comment: Why a regex? Where is this HTML coming from? What is the ultimate problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Sinc Javascript doesn't support lookbehind assertions, you will need to use a capturing group which shouldn't be a problem. I'm not entirely sure what you really want and if you only have `</span>` or if there is also `<span>` or other unknown circumstances. Based on the current requirements, I've written the following regex `<\/span>((?:(?!<\/span>)[\s\S])+)$`. [Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/gQ6rT3)

Comment: Hey HamZa, Thank you for the answer, I can see the regex work as expected, Can you just tell me if i'm right about that when there is only $ at the end of the pattern the string is being tested from the end?

Comment: HamZa, I will be happy if you can explain the regex process, I do understand most of it but mabye you can help me, Also if you add it as an answer i can approve your answer.

Comment: Why a regex? Where is this HTML coming from? What is the ultimate problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Because regex is working i just need to understand how.

Comment: HamZa, Thank you very much, I think i got it now.

Comment: @AvielFadida Sorry for the late reply but it seems [ridgerunner](http://stackoverflow.com/users/433790) has come with a more sophisticated regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Don't parse HTML using Regex

First, you are asking for trouble if you decide to parse HTML using regex for any production/important code.

That said, for non-critial rough editing purposes, HamZa's pattern works just fine. Here is a slightly more complex, (but more efficient) pattern in the form of a tested JavaScript function:

```js
function processText(text) {
/*  # Capture in $1, everything following last SPAN element.
    <\/span\s*>        # Last SPAN close tag.
    (                  # $1: Everything after last SPAN.
      [^<]*            # Zero or more non start-of-tag chars.
      (?:              # Zero or more non-SPAN tags.
        <              # Allow start of any HTML tag, but
        (?!\/?span\b)  # only if not start a SPAN tag.
        [^<]*          # Zero or more non start-of-tag chars.
      )*               # End zero or more non-SPAN tags.
    )                  # End $1: Everything after last SPAN.
    $                  # Anchor to end of string.
*/
    var re = /<\/span\s*>([^<]*(?:<(?!\/?span\b)[^<]*)*)$/i;
    var m = text.match(re);
    return (m) ? m[1] : '';
}
```

The regex is also presented (as a multi-line comment) in free-spacing mode with indentation and comments describing each bite-size regex chunk.

### Learning Regex

For more info on how to write a good regex, I recommend reading the tuorial at: [regular-expressions.info/](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). If you would like to become a regex guru, then you would be well served by reading: [Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124)

Comment: Great way of commenting a regular expression!